# File Permission GPO

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

I am trying to use a GPO to apply permissions for a group of users to a specific folder located on their c: drive. I am running into some issues where the GPO is only partially applying the permissions - meaning it is not propagating through. Below are the setting I have configured:

[image: GPO Settings]

On the folder, I can see where the top folder has the users listed but the subfolders do not. The folder permissions are not populating to the subfolders. Am I missing something in my configuration?

Comment: You need to give enough information to get an idea of what's wrong. Questions like: 'Has anyone run into this before?' are better suited for a forum or discussion platform. I voted you close until you provide more specifics, for example the actual folder ACL after the GPO was applied.

Comment: are you sure the subfolders have permission inheritance enabled? From the two options given in the GPO settings, I would assume the first option only works if inheritance wasn't disabled on the subfolders. The second option should re-enable inheritance on the subfolders and then propagate the inheritable permissions.